# Capture worksheet formulas in VBA format

Tags: vba, excel

I had been searching for a simple way to capture worksheet formulas in VBA format. I came up with a solution below, which I wanted to share.

With any luck this could be useful to someone down the road. Suggestions for improvement are welcome.

```
Public Const vbQuadrupleQuote As String = """""" 'represents 2 double quotes for use in VBA R1C1 formulas ("")
Public Const vbDoubleQuote As String = """" 'represents 1 double quote (")
Public Const vbSingleQuote As String = "'" 'represents 1 single quote (')

Sub CaptureFormulas()  'simplifies the capturing of worksheet formulas in VBA format

'Peter Domanico, May 2017

'Steps:

'(1) place this script in your personal macro workbook
'(2) open Immediate Window in VBA (Control + G)
'(3) run this script and follow prompts
'(4) a With statement containing formulas for your selection will be printed to the Immediate Window
'(5) you can use this With statement in any script

Dim ws As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim MyString As String
Dim MyColumn As Variant
Dim MyRow As Variant
Dim LastRow As String
Dim MyRange As String
Dim MyFormula As String

'set worksheet string
ws = "Activesheet" 'change this as needed

'error handling
On Error GoTo OuttaHere

'select range
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select range to capture", ": )", Type:=8)

'determine formula type
MyQuestion = MsgBox(Prompt:="Fill formulas to last row?", _
            Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="???")

Debug.Print "Dim ws as Worksheet" 'change this as needed
Debug.Print "Set ws = Activesheet" 'change this as needed
Debug.Print "LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row" 'change this as needed
Debug.Print "With ws" 'change this as needed

For Each rng In rng
    MyColumn = rng.Column
    CurrentRow = rng.Row
    Select Case MyQuestion
        Case vbYes
            LastRow = "LastRow"
        Case vbNo
            LastRow = CurrentRow
    End Select
    MyRange = ".Range(.Cells(" & CurrentRow & "," & MyColumn & "),.Cells(" & LastRow & "," & MyColumn & "))="
    MyFormula = rng.FormulaR1C1
    MyFormula = Replace(MyFormula, vbDoubleQuote, vbQuadrupleQuote)
    MyString = MyRange & vbDoubleQuote & MyFormula & vbDoubleQuote
    Debug.Print MyString
Next rng

Debug.Print "End With"

MsgBox "See Immediate Window in VBA", vbInformation, ": )"

OuttaHere:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

First *design* problem is that you're outputting to the *immediate pane*, which isn't *meant* to hold data like this - it will only ever display up to 255 lines, which means as soon as your range has more than 250-some rows, your code stops being useful.

First *code* problem is that `Option Explicit` is missing, and you have undeclared variables:

- `MyQuestion` (which is really an *answer*, since it's a `vbMsgBoxResult`) isn't declared.
- `CurrentRow` isn't declared.

Then you have declared variables that aren't used anywhere:

- `MyRow` isn't used.

You're not validating `rng`, so if the `InputBox` gets cancelled, you get a run-time error 424 "Object Required" and jump `OuttaHere` - which isn't too bad, except for the fact that getting valid user input is a concern in its own right, and really belongs in its own dedicated function.

```
    Set rng = SelectRangeToCapture
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

```
'@Description "Prompts for a Range. Returns Nothing if no selection is made."
Private Function SelectRangeToCapture() As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set SelectRangeToCapture = Application.InputBox("Select range to capture", ": )", Type:=8)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

It doesn't feel right that you need to check `MyQuestion` for every single iteration of that loop - the value is the same every time, you're wasting cycles here. `MyQuestion` should be named `fillToLastRow` and be a `Boolean`:

```
fillToLastRow = MsgBox(...) = vbYes
```

And then the `LastRow` assignment can be a simple `IIf` function result:

```
LastRow = IIf(fillToLastRow, "LastRow", CStr(currentRow))
```

Note the *explicit* type conversion for `currentRow`, from `Long` to `String`.

---

The generated code needs to be indented and properly spaced. Lack of whitespace between operators and operands can easily turn into compile errors, because of how VBA interprets [type hints](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2960/type-hints#t=201705161502348046678) - not necessarily here in *this* code, but lack of whitespace turning `&` concatenation operator into a `&` type hint on a variable or literal value is a quite recurrent, easily avoided question on Stack Overflow.

The `LastRow` logic assumes column A contains data: the reference column should be based on `rng` instead.

I'm also a bit puzzled about why you would want to use R1C1 notation in the formulas, but maybe it's just because I never needed to use it in 15 years.

---

Why not go all the way, reference the VBIDE type library and actually output your generated code to an actual procedure, in an actual module? That way you wouldn't be limited to 255 lines. Although.. I wonder if that's a good idea, given VBA won't even *compile* a procedure that's more than 10,000 lines, or a module with more than 65,535 lines - in other words, `rng.Count` needs to be capped and validated, otherwise you either lose data, or generate code that can't even compile.

---

In general I don't like VBA code that *requires* frequent modifications. Code should be written to *resist* change - yours *embraces* change with arms wide open, pretty much as part of its own specification, including instructions-in-comments.

Speaking of comments... Comments should say *why*, not *what*. These comments say nothing that the code doesn't already say:

```
'error handling
On Error GoTo OuttaHere
```

```
'select range
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select range to capture", ": )", Type:=8)
```

```
'set worksheet string
ws = "Activesheet"
```

---

One last note about naming: `OuttaHere` isn't normally a label you'd find in professionally-written code. `CleanExit` would be more appropriate. `MyXxxxx` identifiers are annoying, too: such names don't convey much information, other than a vague data type that belongs to *something* (or *someone?*). Take the time to name things, meaningfully.

- `MyRange` holds an *assignment instruction*, not a `Range`.
- `MyFormula` holds the Excel formula in the current cell.
- `MyString` holds a VBA instruction.

And so on.

Comment: Quite impressive :)

Comment: @Mat's Mug thanks for the suggestions! I appreciate the time you put into your responses. I'm certain I can put these to good use.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your 'final version' I figured I would offer some advice. While the great advice offered by Mat's Mug and Vityata seem to have helped you, it also seems as though you are still not quite there. First code, then explanations:

```
Option Explicit

' Avoid prefixing constants with vb. This has special meaning since vbSomeEnum is used to denote an enum
' that is generally used within functions, subs, or classes.

' The naming convention for constants is SOME_FOO where all words are fully capitalized and separated by an underscore.
' Additionally, there is a function for getting these strings. See below:
' Double Quote - Chr(34) - "
' Two Double Quotes - Chr(34)&Chr(34) - ""
' Single Quote - Chr(39) - '

Public Const vbQuadrupleQuote As String = """"""
Public Const vbDoubleQuote As String = """"
Public Const vbSingleQuote As String = "'"

' Ideally, denote your subroutines as 'Public' or 'Private'. This allows your code to be more explicit.
' Additionally, your subroutines should be slightly descriptive. What formulas are you capturing? What is the method doing?
' CaptureFormulas in itself is quite unexplanatory.
Sub CaptureFormulas()
    ' Use proper indentation.
    ' The Dim block below can be a code smell. It can make it difficult to see the use of variables
    ' and it can also make it harder to debug your code. I strongly suggest the advice of 'Declare your variables as close to their first use as possible'
    Dim Rng             As Range

    ' Why declare these variables as variant? This in itself is a code smell. Variants should only be used as a last resort (and usually, it is when either
    ' a function needs to return multiple types, or when you are creating an array.
    Dim CurrentColumn   As Variant
    Dim CurrentRow      As Variant

    ' I dont understand the intent of LastRow as String. It is actually being used as a long. As such, declare as long and use explicit
    ' string conversion functions if needed.
    Dim LastRow         As String
    Dim RangeString     As String
    Dim FormulaString   As String

    ' Use a more descriptive variable name. Looking at 'Ws' I assume it is a worksheet, but it is instead a sheet name.
    ' As such, consider 'TargetSheetName' or 'NameOfOutputSheet' or something similar. In turn, your code will become easier to read.
    Dim Ws              As String
    Dim FinalString     As String

    ' These variable names are also somewhat misleading. FormulaType isnt a type at all. It is actually a 'FillToLastRow'.
    ' SubOrNot is also not fully clear. It is really 'PrintEntireSubroutine'.
    Dim FormulaType     As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim SubOrNot        As VbMsgBoxResult

    ' I would strongly recommend setting a Range variable to equal the selection, and then refer to that.
    ' Reason being, if your user somehow interrupts the code the selection at this line may be different from the selection
    ' at a later line.
    Ws = Selection.Worksheet.Name

    ' If you are going to denote a title, at least make it useful. '???' should be something like 'Formula Fill Length' or something similar.
    FormulaType = MsgBox(Prompt:="Fill formulas to last row?", _
                Buttons:=vbYesNoCancel, Title:="???")

    ' This would be much better written as:
    ' If Formulatype = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
    ' It is much clearer that way
    Select Case FormulaType
        Case vbCancel
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    SubOrNot = MsgBox(Prompt:="Print full subscript?", _
                Buttons:=vbYesNoCancel, Title:="???")

    Select Case SubOrNot
        Case vbCancel
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    ' Just a suggestion: the user should be allowed to title the new subscript. If you always have
    ' 'Sub NewScript()' there will inevitably be a conflict.
    Select Case SubOrNot
        Case vbYes
            Debug.Print "Sub NewScript ()" & vbNewLine
    End Select
    Debug.Print vbTab & "Dim Ws as Worksheet"
    Debug.Print vbTab & "Set Ws = Worksheets(" & vbDoubleQuote & Ws & vbDoubleQuote & ")"
    Debug.Print vbTab & "LastRow = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row" & vbNewLine
    Debug.Print vbTab & "With Ws"

    For Each Rng In Selection
        CurrentColumn = Rng.Column
        CurrentRow = Rng.Row

        ' It looks like you actually need a new variable here to be clearer.
        ' LastRow isn't being used as lastrow, it is being used as FormulaRow and as such, it is unclear why you would
        ' change the value of LastRow to equal 'LastRow' or 'CurrentRow' whereas 'FormulaRow' being changed would make more sense.
        Select Case FormulaType
            Case vbYes
                LastRow = "LastRow"
            Case vbNo
                LastRow = CurrentRow
        End Select
        RangeString = vbTab & vbTab & ".Range(.Cells(" & CurrentRow & "," & CurrentColumn & "),.Cells(" & LastRow & "," & CurrentColumn & ")).FormulaR1C1="

        ' This can be a one-liner, and as a result your code would be cleaner
        ' Debug.Print RangeString & vbDoubleQuote & Replace(Rng.FormulaR1C1, vbDoubleQuote, vbQuadrupleQuote) & vbDoubleQuote
        FormulaString = Rng.FormulaR1C1
        FormulaString = Replace(FormulaString, vbDoubleQuote, vbQuadrupleQuote)
        FinalString = RangeString & vbDoubleQuote & FormulaString & vbDoubleQuote
        Debug.Print FinalString
    Next Rng

    Debug.Print vbTab & "End With" & vbNewLine
    Select Case SubOrNot
        Case vbYes
            Debug.Print "End Sub"
    End Select
    Debug.Print vbNewLine

End Sub
```

### The Routine as a Tool

Before I get into any of my suggestions below, I can't stress enough how important it is for someone to not use a 'tool' like this versus learning how to code efficiently. There are plenty of macro-recorders out there, and its nice to have something 'quick and dirty' when you're learning, or when you just dont have time to code it yourself. That said, I cant imagine a scenario in which using a tool like this is more beneficial to the user than learning the 'why' of what the code is using.

That isnt to be harsh, or to say that this project is unusable. I am a huge proponent for writing code to learn how to code. In itself, this project has taught you about coding more than not writing it would have. Does that justify using this instead of continuing to develop as a programmer? Certainly not. In fact, I would give yourself, at most, three months before this project is dead. If, at the end of the next three months, you find this tool still useful then you are doing something wrong.

Particularly, you are not yet using arrays for your loops, and as a result you are directly referencing the sheet. I can guarantee that, for larger loops, this is costing you time. For a bit of perspective, I can loop through 60k rows of data in a matter of seconds (if that). Try doing that with a range reference...well I would recommend not wasting your time.

I can't stress enough: **use this project as a learning tool, but not as a practical means of writing code well**.

### Pet Peeves

Most of the *problems* with your code are really stylistic choices, or decisions you've made that you just didnt have enough experience to know why they're bad decisions. Whenever I review code, I look for the things I used to do (and that were holding me back) but I just didnt know it yet.

First: naming conventions. Spend some time learning them, and learning why they exist.

1. A constant (`Const`) should follow the UPPER_CASE style. This makes it really easy to see when the constant is then used within the code.
2. Special prefixes (`xl`, `vb`, etc.) hold special meaning, and should  not be used within variable names. While it may make it *look* nicer, it will also make it more difficult for an outside reader to determine why the supposed `vbConstant` `vbSomeFoo` is acting strangely, and they will assume that it is a bug within the language. They will not innately know it was a bug you introduced.

Use existing functions/code where possible. This not only reduces the risk of bugs, but it can, at times, be more efficient. For example, `Chr(34)` denotes a `"` and can be used instead of introducing an entirely new variable. This also makes your code easy to read. When I, as a reader, see `Chr(34)` I know what it is, whereas if I see `vbDoubleQuote` I have to look for its meaning.

**Indent your code properly**. I don't think this point can be over-stressed yet it doesn't always sink in properly. If you ever have code that is touching the window, aside from the Sub/Function declarations and Line Labels, something is wrong. For example:

```
Sub Foo()
Dim Bar as Baz
DoSomething(Bar)
End Sub
```

Is much harder to read than:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim Bar as Baz
    DoSomething(Bar)
End Sub
```

Especially when you have:

```
Sub Foo()
Dim Bar as Baz
DoSomething(Bar)
End Sub
Sub Bar()
Dim Baz as Foo
DoSomething(Bar)
End Sub
```

While your code isnt hugging the left-hand side of the window, there are lines that, by their indentation, seem like they are actually procedure declarations (Sub Foo's) and not declarations within a procedure.

### Dim Blocks

This gets its own header because it is something often overlooked. It wasn't long ago when, like you, my Dim blocks were like the glossary at the end of a textboox chapter. At times, I was proud of them. "Look at how much I must be accomplishing with this sub. I have so many variables declared!" "My Dim block looks so nice, and uniform. Surely my code is organized." Hyperbole, of course, but I truly was proud of my code. Then came along Mat's Mug to trample all over it (indirectly). I saw his advice about how they can actually be ineffective, ugly, and work against code cleanliness. I decided to give his way a try, and sure enough my code went from "Okay" to "Much Better".

Why are they bad? First, they encourage lazy coding. When you are declaring all your variables at the top, there is no need to question 'Do I really need this here?' and further 'Should this actually be a function?'. These two steps are vital to cleaner code. Even further, they make it more difficult to see when a variable is declared but unused, or when the name doesnt fit the function.

In short, declare your variables as close to their first use as possible, and as a result you should see an improvement in your code.

### Variant - The VBA Programming Menace

Variants can be used effectively, and they do have their place within code, so don't think I just write them off completely. I have a few procedures where I use Variants like:

```
Private Function GetFoo(ByVal InputBar as String) as Variant
    If InputBar <> vbNullString Then
        GetFoo = 10
    Else
        GetFoo = vbNullString
    End If
End Function
```

What this allows me to do (primarily for data) is use an empty value if the input condition is invalid (null) while still returning a numeric (or some other non-string) if the input is valid. Likewise:

```
Dim SomeArray as Variant
SomeArray = SomeRange.Value
```

This allows me to convert a range to an array, and then use those values more efficiently. Variants do have their place when used properly, but they shouldn't be used out of laziness.

For example, in your code, `CurrentColumn` (which should be `CurrentColumnIndex`) and `CurrentRow` (which should be `CurrentRowIndex`) are used as numerics (and as such, should be Longs) but are declared as Variants. I assume, it is because they are then implicitly (without explicit direction) converted to strings, but even this doesn't justify the use of variants.

You could do something like:

```
Dim CurrentColumnIndex as Long
CurrentColumnIndex = SomeNumeric
...more code...
SomeString = CString(SomeNumeric)
SomeLongerString = Chr(34) & CString(SomeNumeric) & Chr(34)
```

I highly suggest learning Type conversion functions as well.

### In Closing

There is much more to learn beyond what I have highlighted, so don't get discouraged when, at the end of making these improvements, you still have more to learn. The key is to improve with a purpose. I strongly suggest learning about 'Clean Code'. I left notes within your code as well to help you along. The most important part is that you hold yourself accountable for improvement. I can honestly say that my code from three months ago is bad, and my code from six months ago is repulsive. If you can look back and not see the flaws within your code, you arent pushing yourself enough to improve.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and thoughtful response, it's truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would have improved it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const vbQuadrupleQuote As String = """"""        '("")
Public Const vbDoubleQuote As String = """"             '(")
Public Const vbSingleQuote As String = "'"              '(')

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rng             As Range
    Dim lngCol          As Long
    Dim lngRow          As Long

    Dim strCapture      As String
    Dim strRange        As String
    Dim strFormula      As String

    strCapture = "Public Sub WsGenerator" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Now(), ":", ""), ".", ""), " ", "")
    strCapture = strCapture & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Dim ws as Worksheet"
    strCapture = strCapture & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Set ws = Activesheet"
    strCapture = strCapture & vbCrLf & vbTab & "LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row"
    strCapture = strCapture & vbCrLf & vbTab & "With ws"

    For Each rng In Selection

        lngCol = rng.Column
        lngRow = rng.Row

        strRange = ".Range(.Cells(" & lngRow & "," & lngCol & "),.Cells(" & lngRow & "," & lngCol & "))="
        strFormula = rng.FormulaR1C1
        strFormula = Replace(strFormula, vbDoubleQuote, vbQuadrupleQuote)
        strCapture = strCapture & vbCrLf & vbTab & vbTab & strRange & vbDoubleQuote & strFormula & vbDoubleQuote

    Next rng

    strCapture = strCapture & vbCrLf & vbTab & "End With"
    strCapture = strCapture & vbCrLf & "End sub"
    Debug.Print strCapture

End Sub
```

Pros:

- The code comes out formatted and with `Sub` `End Sub`
- Selection is used
- No msgboxes (I dislike them)
- Less variables
- We only print once (although, in general it is better to export the string to a Notepad file, because the immediate window would not show more than about 250 lines).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up settling on this as my final version. Thanks everyone for their suggestions:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const vbQuadrupleQuote As String = """""" 'represents 2 double quotes for use in VBA R1C1 formulas ("")
Public Const vbDoubleQuote As String = """" 'represents 1 double quote (")
Public Const vbSingleQuote As String = "'" 'represents 1 single quote (')

Sub CaptureFormulas()  'simplifies the capturing of worksheet formulas in VBA format

'Peter Domanico, May 2017

'Steps:

'(1) place this script in your personal macro workbook
'(2) open Immediate Window in VBA (Control + G)
'(3) select range to capture in Excel
'(4) run this script and follow prompts
'(5) a subscript or With statement containing formulas for your selection will be printed to the Immediate Window
'(6) use this subscript or With statement in your code

'set dims
Dim Rng             As Range
Dim CurrentColumn   As Variant
Dim CurrentRow      As Variant
Dim LastRow         As String
Dim RangeString     As String
Dim FormulaString   As String
Dim Ws              As String
Dim FinalString     As String
Dim FormulaType     As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim SubOrNot        As VbMsgBoxResult

'set worksheet string
Ws = Selection.Worksheet.Name

'fill formula dynamically to last row?
FormulaType = MsgBox(Prompt:="Fill formulas to last row?", _
            Buttons:=vbYesNoCancel, Title:="???")

'exit sub on user cancel
Select Case FormulaType
    Case vbCancel
        Exit Sub
End Select

'print complete subscript to Immediate Window?
SubOrNot = MsgBox(Prompt:="Print full subscript?", _
            Buttons:=vbYesNoCancel, Title:="???")

'exit sub on user cancel
Select Case SubOrNot
    Case vbCancel
        Exit Sub
End Select

'prints items neccesary for script
Select Case SubOrNot
    Case vbYes
        Debug.Print "Sub NewScript ()" & vbNewLine
End Select
Debug.Print vbTab & "Dim Ws as Worksheet"
Debug.Print vbTab & "Set Ws = Worksheets(" & vbDoubleQuote & Ws & vbDoubleQuote & ")"
Debug.Print vbTab & "LastRow = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row" & vbNewLine
Debug.Print vbTab & "With Ws"

'loop through each range in selection
For Each Rng In Selection
    CurrentColumn = Rng.Column
    CurrentRow = Rng.Row
    Select Case FormulaType
        Case vbYes
            LastRow = "LastRow"
        Case vbNo
            LastRow = CurrentRow
    End Select
    RangeString = vbTab & vbTab & ".Range(.Cells(" & CurrentRow & "," & CurrentColumn & "),.Cells(" & LastRow & "," & CurrentColumn & ")).FormulaR1C1="
    FormulaString = Rng.FormulaR1C1
    FormulaString = Replace(FormulaString, vbDoubleQuote, vbQuadrupleQuote)
    FinalString = RangeString & vbDoubleQuote & FormulaString & vbDoubleQuote
    Debug.Print FinalString
Next Rng

'prints closing items neccesary for script
Debug.Print vbTab & "End With" & vbNewLine
Select Case SubOrNot
    Case vbYes
        Debug.Print "End Sub"
End Select
Debug.Print vbNewLine

End Sub
```